# jQuery submit a form inside its own .on(submit) handler, endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to listen for the form submit action, stop it from submitting the form, hit the tokenize method (which could take a second), wait for its response to finish, and THEN submit the form when that is completed.

I cannot simply `return true;` inside the `.on('submit')` handler, as that happens before tokenize finishes.

Also noticed jQuery has deprecated `.submit()`, and to use `.on('submit')` or `.trigger('submit')`. But that still puts me in the same loop.

What am I missing here.

```
$("#testform").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hostedFields.tokenize(function(err, payload) {
        // handle error conditions
        // else continue with submit:
        $("#nonce").val(payload.nonce);
        $("#testform").submit(); // blaaaah endless loop !!!
    });
});
```

```
<form id="testform">
    <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="testnonce" value="" />
    ... other elements of the form not part of the question ...
    <input type="submit" name="boo" value="Damnit" />
</form>
```

*This is working with the "Braintree Hosted Fields" system. Their examples say to do exactly this, but this just kills the browser with an endless loop.*

*Note: do not copy the `id="submit"` from braintree code, on the submit button.*

Comment: Did you try using the native Javascript submit() method on the form DOM element? It will submit the form without triggering jQuery submit event.

Comment: @esQmo_ Why not write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] This is an edited answer as OP omitted some information.

Did you try using the native Javascript submit() method on the form DOM element? It will submit the form without triggering jQuery submit event.

````js
$("#testform").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this; // save reference to form
    hostedFields.tokenize(function(err, payload) {
        // handle error conditions
        // else continue with submit:
        $("#nonce").val(payload.nonce);
        form.submit(); // use native JS submit
    });
});```
````

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip on the difference between jquery and js native submits. Something I actually didn't know about! Yay.